# What's wrong with my binomial expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to use the binomial formula to expand the function $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$

$\dfrac{1}{1-x}=(1-x)^{-1}=1+(-1)x+(-1)(-2)\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+(-1)(-2)(-3)\dfrac{x^3}{3!}...$

The sign are all wrong they get much more similar to the series of $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$, which is an alternating series.

So what did I do wrong here?

Comment: Thanks! I will try again

Comment: You did the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^{-1}$.

Comment: @JamesWarthington You're welcome. Since my comment wasn't really asking for clarification, or anything like that, but was really an answer, as brief as it is, I moved it to an answer and deleted my comment. Sorry about that; I should've just given an answer directly instead.

Comment: You forgot the $(-1)^n$.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing $x$ with $-x$ in your expansion since $1 - x = 1 + (-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by long division you get $$\frac {1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+....$$